# strictly positive in unital $C*$ algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C*$ algebra. $a\in A_+$ is called strictly positive if  $\overline{aAa}=A$. Prove that $a\in A_+$ is strictly positive iff $a$ is invertable. I proved one direction : if $a$ is invertable, then $a$ is strictly positive , but I have no  idea how to prove the other direction. 
 Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\overline{aAa}=A$, there is $x\in A$ such that $\|axa-1\|<1/2$. Therefore $axa$ is invertible. This implies that $a$ has left and right inverse and consequently it is invertible.

Comment: I see that $a$ has a left inverse and a right inverse. Don't those two have to coincide for $a$ to be invertible?

Comment: ah no, I think I just forgot, that $a$ is hermitian ( since positive )