# Strictly positive element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Searching about strictly positive elements, I found [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340689/strictly-positive-in-unital-c-algebra). I tried to solve it, and the following is my attempt. Please check my proof. Is it correct?

Suppose $a$ is strictly positive. By definition, $\overline {aAa} =A$. Also $\overline {aAa}$ is generated by $a$. $1\in A$, so there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n(a)$ such that $1=\lim p_n(a)$. Also $0\not\in \sigma(1)$, and $\sigma(1)=\lim\sigma(p_n(a)) =\lim p_n(\sigma(a))$.  Thus $0\not\in \sigma(a^n)$ for every $n$, which implies that $a$ is invertible.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost never true that $\overline{aAa}$ is generated by $a$. Note that $a$ is positive, so the algebra it generates is abelian.

For the second part of the argument (which is irrelevant to the exercise, but let me address it for your benefit): your write "$\lim\sigma(p_n(a))$"; what do you mean by the limit of a sequence of sets? Also, when you consider polynomials, you need to be careful in cases like this because you want polynomials with no constant term. Any such polynomial $p_n(a)$ is of the form $aq_n(a)$, so none can be invertible if $a$ is not invertible; and the set of invertible operators is open, so an invertible cannot be a limit of non-invertibles. Thus if $aq_n(a)\to 1$, then eventually $aq_n(a)$ is invertible, which implies that $a$ is invertible.

Comment: For the second time: a positive operator generates an abelian algebra. Are you suggesting that all C$^*$-algebras are abelian? Looking at Murphy's text, you are missing the word "hereditary".

Comment: It says "the **hereditary** C$^*$-algebra generated by $a$".

Comment: Please read my last comment. It doesn't say "the C$^*$-algebra generated by $a$ is hereditary"; it says "the hereditary C$^*$-algebra generated by $a$".

Comment: No, it does not mean that. It means, as it says, " the hereditary C$^*$-algebra generated by $a$".