# Strictly positive element in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $a\in A^+$. $a$ is said to be strictly positive if $aA$ is dense in $A$.

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Does there exist another sufficient and necessary condition to ensure that there exists a strictly positive element in $M$?

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in unital $C^*$-algebras, a positive element $a$ is strictly positive if and only if it is invertible. Now, since von Neumann algebras are unital, this would be such a condition.

To see a proof of this, confer this question:

[strictly positive elements in $C^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339989/strictly-positive-elements-in-c-algebra)